# Polymer: Listen for events triggered on child elements from light DOM

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a `container-element` with behavior `_checkSomething` that needs to happen on tap down *for any child* `item-element` within its light DOM.

```
<container-element>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ items ]]">

        <!-- Doesn't work; scope cannot access _checkSomething within shadow DOM: -->  
        <item-element on-down="_checkSomething"></item-element>

    </template>
</container-element>

<dom-module id="container-element">
    <template>

        <content select="item-element"></content>

    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "container-element",
            listeners: {

                // This listener is also impossible, since it's
                // meant for a unique id, whereas I want to target
                // every child item-element:

                'item-element.down': '_checkSomething'
            },

            _checkSomething: function(){
                console.log('checking...');
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Normally to accomplish this, I would not insert the `dom-repeat` `item-elements` from the light DOM; I would put them inside `container-element`'s template, where I can set `<item-element on-down="_checkSomething">` for each item. In this case, I don't think I have the luxury. `container-element` is really a simplified interface for a drag-drop container with a bunch of custom logic that needs to be checked on tap down, which I want to hide from the person that implements it.

It seems to me that my only way forward is to have `item-element` emit a special event, listened to by `container-element`. However I'm not sure if `container-element` would be able to hear an event coming from its light DOM and we would have the same problem..?

Any ideas on how to trigger `_checkSomething` with this template setup?

Comment: I think you complicate your work, because use `<content>` and inside it  use  `<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ items ]]">`. First try to handle the event without using `<content>` tag and add you template with items inside the dom of container-element.

Comment: Yes, Dmitry - that's how I normally would do it, and in fact I've had to switch to that way for now. The reason for my question was: because the real element is way more complex than this simplified example, I wanted to use `<container-element>` as a container to hide drag-drop 'magic' that would happen in response to events in the content's light DOM. This would allow user-developers to forget about the complex dnd logic. Alas, for now I don't think that's possible...